# Inserting variables as well as columns using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, sqlbulkcopy

I'm just learning and have written this code to copy data from one database to another (LOTSCON) = source, CON = destination.

The code all works and copies the data across, however it is based on checkboxes on a previous datagridview form.

The user selects which records to import, but also selects `CHKCOMMUNITY` which means this patient is a nursing home patient.

In the NEW table, there is a column `nursinghome` which is a bit type.

If the user ticks `chkCommunity` in the datagrid, I want to do the bulk copy but also make sure the `nursinghome` column in the destination table is set to 1.

So I'm not mapping an existing column in the source table..

How can I achieve this?

DO I just import then run a SQL string updating the column based on what I have just entered?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridInst.Rows) 
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkcell = row.Cells["chkimport"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

    if (chkcell.Value != null)
    {             
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(chkcell.Value) == true)
        {
            instid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["clninstid"].Value);
            iscommunity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["chkcommunity"].Value);

            using (SqlConnection lotscon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LOTSConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Person.*, NEWinstitution.institutionname
                                    FROM NEWinstitution INNER JOIN Person ON NEWinstitution.institutionid = Person.InstitutionID
                                    WHERE person.institutionid = @instid", lotscon))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@instid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = instid;

                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    { 
                        adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        lotscon.Open();

                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        adapt.Fill(ds);

                        DataTable dtgenerate = new DataTable();
                        dtgenerate = ds.Tables[0];

                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
                        {
                            using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                            {
                                bc.DestinationTableName = "tblpatient";

                                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("firstname", "pxfirstname");
                                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("lastname", "pxlastname");
                                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("address", "address");
                                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("suburb", "suburb");
                                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("medicareno", "medicarenumber");
                                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("personid", "dispenseid");
                                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("institutionname", "institutionname");
                                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("VAcardid", "repatnumber");
                                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("phonenumber", "phonenumber");

                                con.Open();
                                bc.WriteToServer(dtgenerate);
                                con.Close();
                                lotscon.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach is the problem., Are You reading data, or are you updating, or this is an insert of new data? It certainly is NOT a copy. You need to: 1) read data and display to user. 2) update dataset based on user interactions. 3-A) Update the existing data with the new values. (or) 3-B) Insert new data with new values to a different table. Bulk copy operations are mean to be done fast from a source into the destination without locking, and bypassing the database log. In other words; seems like you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @RicardoC , i can see where I am totally misunderstanding the purpose of bulkcopy.  
Would you advise reading the data, create a dataset that displays as a datagrid where i can make changes OR read and insert into a tmpTbl where i make changes, THEN that gets inserted into the main destination?

Comment: i would modify the data in the grid and update back to the source. no need for temp tables. Please be aware that i have not seen your schema, etc. There could be many other considerations, so this is just a quick advice, in a simplistic way.

Comment: thanks ricardo, i have ended up creating a dataset with results in it which get put into a datagrid where the user can add the extra data into unbound tables